# Change color of graticule label

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm trying to change the color of graticule labels on my openlayers map but I cant make it work. Here is what I'm doing:

```
this.Graticule = new OpenLayers.Control.Graticule({
        numPoints: 2,
        labelled: true,
        lineSymbolizer:{strokeColor: "#ffffff", strokeWidth: 1, strokeOpacity: 0.2},
        labelSymbolizer:{strokeColor: "#ffffff", strokeWidth: 1, strokeOpacity: 0.7}
    });
```

The color lines is changing but I always get black labels.

Can someone help me here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no experience with OpenLayers, but from what I've seen that should work. However, I can't get it to work either. An alternative way is to use CSS, for example:

```
tspan{
    stroke: green;
}
```

However this will have all labels to be green which probably isn't intended. As I said I have no experience with OpenLayers, but maybe there is some way to lock down the CSS rule to only graticule text?

Comment: I put stroke in map div and it worked! But what about the options strokeWidth strokeOpacity?

Comment: I didn't find an option for that, however it should be possible if you google a bit for that. However you can use `font-family: fontName`. You could even create your own font if you would like to go that far.

Comment: Perfect. Now I get it. I'm using **font** and **stroke** css rules in map div to change graticule label. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In order to change the text labels you need to define font attributes:

```
labelSymbolizer: {
    fontColor: "#ffffff",
    fontSize: "12px"
}
```

Comment: There are a variety of other attributes that can be changed as well:

fontColor: "#fff",
fontSize: "12px",
fontFamily: "Courier New, monospace",
fontWeight: "bold",
labelXOffset: "0",
labelYOffset: "0",
labelOutlineColor: "black",
labelOutlineWidth: 3